# Query animate() doesnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
var isOn = false;

$('.switch').on("click",function(){

  if (isOn){


    $('.toggle').animate({
      left:"18px"
    },10,"linear",

     {
      complete: function(){
        $('#label').text("ON");
      }
    });
    isOn = false;



  } else {
    $('.toggle').animate({
      left:"4px"
    }, 10,"linear",
                         {
      complete: function(){
        $('#label').text("OFF");
      }
    });
    isOn = true;
  }

});
```

http://codepen.io/pietrofxq/pen/LpzDE?editors=001

It is a switch on/off made with `jquery`. It was working without the `animate()` method.
I was doing the animation with css, but it was buggy in Internet Explorer.
Here is the original effect: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwatp

Why the complete function in the first link isn't working?

**EDIT: This code is working but still doesnt work properly on IE**

Comment: which Ie version not working?

Comment: The first link. The text is not toggling between the "On" and "Off". The second link is the version that i made that works, but dont work in IE, so i tried to reach the same effect with the animate() function

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be mixing [the two](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) [different signatures](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) of the `.animate` function. If you pass the duration and the easing directly as arguments, you have to do the same for the callback function:

```
$('.toggle').animate({left: "18px"}, 10, "linear", function(){
  $('#label').text("ON");
});
```

OR you have to pass two objects:

```
$('.toggle').animate(
  {
     left:"18px"
  },
  {
    duration: 10,
    easing: "linear",
    complete: function(){
      $('#label').text("ON");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I'm amazed why that not worked as they are from jQuery. Anyway +1

Comment: @Pietro: They are actually quite clear for this function IMO. Either it's `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )` or `.animate( properties, options )`.

Comment: lol, my bad. I'm still not used to jquery docs... if they just used more examples

Comment: @Pietro: You have to read [everything](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete#basic-usage) ;)

Answer (score 0):

now it will work. please check the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/banded_krait/da2kE/

I removed some brackets and `complete:` array key from your code and hope this will work for you.